# How to count repeating lines in a txt file

Tags: c++

So if i have a large text file with lines that repeat, how can I determine the line that repeats the most frequently?

```
    Example
    The dog is brown
    The cat is orange
    The dog is brown
```

This should return 2 for `The Dog is brown`

Comment: Is there a reason for this to be in c++? It's trivial to implement as a shell script.

Comment: Yeah it needs to be c++. It's an exercise

Comment: If this were a list of numbers, how would you solve the problem?  If you had to do it by hand, instead of with the computer, how would you do it?

Comment: Ah an exercise. **What have you tried?**

Comment: Unless you have a really good reason to do otherwise, it's probably easiest to do this with something like `std::unordered_map<std::string, unsigned>`.

Answer (score 2):

Since this appears to be a learning exercise, here is an approach that you can take:

- Make an *associative container*, say, [`map<string,int>`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map) or [`unordered_map<string,int>`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_map) to keep counts
- Read the file line-by-line. For each line that you get increment the count in your associative container
- Once you finished reading the file, walk the container, find the highest count, and store its associated key
- When you are done with the loop, the key that you found and its associated count give the answer to your problem.

One way to understand this approach is to consider the same problem, but with strings replaced with numbers. Now all you need to do is writing a loop performing `count[number]++` for each `number` in the list. The approach described above is essentially the same thing, but you use a string instead of the number for your index.